# Pass by reference - const_buffer object in C++

Tags: c++, boost, vector, boost-asio

I am using Boost libraries (boost_1_53_0) for my application. The area of interest is a module which sends messages over UDP. Check out the below code section (I have stripped out unnecessary code sections which won't impact the functionality).

```
int send()
{
    .
    .
    .
    std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer> bufs;

    writeMessage(bufs);

    /* If I comment out writeMessage and fill variable
     * bufs the same way its populated in writeMessage,
     * things work */

    udpSocket.send_to(bufs, endPoint);
}

void writeMessage(std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer>& bufs)
{
    /* Populate data..... */

    bufs.push_back(boost::asio::const_buffer(data1, sizeof(data1)));
    bufs.push_back(boost::asio::const_buffer(data2, sizeof(data2)));
    .
    .
    .
    bufs.push_back(boost::asio::const_buffer(datan, sizeof(datan)));
}
```

I am using wireshark to check the message sent out of the system. For some reason, incorrect data is being sent out of the system. Is pass by reference of the variable bufs correct ? The same piece of code is working for a older g++ and Boost version.

If I comment out writeMessage and manually fill the vector bufs in send() function, things are fine. Only if I use the function writeMessage(), data is being corrupted.

I recently upgraded to g++ 4.6.3 and Boost 1_53_0 and seeing this problem. I am using Ubuntu 64-bit machine. All the libraries are compiled for 64 bit.

Comment: Have you used a debugger and set breakpoints to see where data is getting corrupted? Your pass-by-reference certainly looks fine to me.

Comment: Do you think anything would make the `data1,2..n` to have bad values/size in `setMessages`. Also just try sending one data buf and see if you get it alright and maybe take it from there.

Comment: @us2012 I used gdb and checked the memory locations, 2 bytes were corrupted, I am sending a 22 byte message and 9th, 10th bytes were corrupted. But even then the message coming out of the system is entirely different.

Comment: @ArunR I sent a single block of 2 bytes but even then the sent message was wrong.

Comment: What are 'data1'...'datan'? Do you manage these buffers lifespan correctly?

Comment: @Neo Does wireshark tell you how the buffer differs - does it get two chars, but different values. Do you get to see what is received and compare it to sent data? You also say it works if you use older versions.Can you just revert the Boost version back but keep the current gcc and see if it works.

Comment: @ArunR Yes, from wireshark I can see that I receive 2 bytes but both the bytes are wrong, the sent and received bytes are not related but the received first byte is always 0xb8. I will check if I can use the older Boost version and use the existing environment.

Comment: @IgorR 'data1'...'datan' are local character buffers, below is a detailed code snippet of my write function.`char data1[2]; memcpy(data1, DataSource, 2); bufs.push_back(boost::asio::const_buffer(data1, sizeof(data1)));`

Comment: `buffer` (and `const_buffer`) functions do not copy your buffer, they just adapt it to match `ConstBufferSequence` concept. So, the bottom line is that you attempt to pass a local buffer to an async. i/o function. This won't work, because the buffer must outlive the i/o operation.

Comment: @IgorR Thanks for the suggestion, you were correct that was exactly the issue. I am new to C++ and I didn't know much about buffer and const_buffer. But I wonder how the code is working on a older platform. Is it a problem with older GCC ? How can I catch such issues, I didn't see a warning from the compiler for this. Can lint or similar tools catch such issues ? Please post your solution as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common pitfall is to forget that `buffer` (or `const_buffer`) functions [do not copy the underlying buffer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html) (scroll down the above page to see explanations and examples) - they just adapt it to `MutableBufferSequence` (or [`ConstBufferSequence`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ConstBufferSequence.html)) concept. This means that the buffer must outlive the asynchronous operation.

Why did your program use to work with some other compiler / compiler flags / boost version / etc? It's just a matter of luck. Your `data1` ... `dataN`arrays of `char` were allocated [on the call stack](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/09/06/stack-frame-layout-on-x86-64/), within the function stack frame (under `RBP`). When `writeMessage` function exits, its stack frame is deallocated. The subsequent function calls would allocate stack frames in about the same place where `writeMessage` did. But as long as they do not use the stack addresses of `data1` ... `dataN`, the old data may remain intact there. Slightly different compiler flags or function implementation will change the picture.